# Sending email in .NET through Google Apps from an Addon Domain

Tags: c#, .net, email, gmail

I realize that questions about sending email from C# / .NET through Gmail have been asked before, but I don't believe that this specific scenario has been addressed.

On our Google Apps account, we have our main domain (which we use to login), but we also have add-on domains (domain alias) which we are able to send mail from. Every account as an associated for each add-on domain (domain alias) i.e.

- username@maindomain.com (maindomain that we login under)
- username@seconddomain.com (alias that we can both send/receive from. received email gets delivered to inbox of email above - username@maindomain.com)

Through the Gmail interface, Gmail app, etc. we are able to send email from any of the domain aliases. The "From" box has a dropdown to select which address to send from:

- username@maindomain.com
- username@seconddomain.com
- ...
- username@lastdomain.com

Is it possible to replicate this through .NET? Here is the code that I tried, but it always defaults back to sending from the login account.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add("recipient@domain.com");

mail.Subject = "Test Message";
mail.Body = "<html><body>Message body.</body></html>";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

// Credentials for Google Apps Account//
string sendEmailsFrom = "username@mydomain.com";
string sendEmailsFromPassword = "password";

// Email address from Googel Apps Account - Addon Domain //
mail.From(new MailAddress("username@myotherdomain.com"))

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Timeout = 10000;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sendEmailsFrom, sendEmailsFromPassword);
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Have you ever tried in the Gmail interface to login with any domain besides the main?  With MailMessage, the from account and the login must be the same.  So to work you must be able to login to the same domain as the from address.

Comment: Unfortunately, Gmail does not allow you to login using any of the domain aliases (even when using the same email account user). That being the case, I am starting to think that it is not possible to send email from a Google Apps domain alias...